# SEM Interpretation

Tags: mean, standard-error

Standard error of the mean (SEM) represents the accuracy of the mean. Here's my question/doubt. 
    Does higher the SEM mean higher the accuracy of the mean?
    To be more precise, what indicates more accuracy of the mean? sem = 3.5 or sem = 1.5?

This may seem odd but it keeps on pestering me for a very long time. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SEM [quantifies how far your estimate of the mean is likely to be from the true population mean](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat)keyconcepts_sem.htm). So smaller means more precise / accurate. In that sense, SEM=1.5 indicates that your sample mean is a more accurate estimate of the population mean than if SEM was 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the sample mean is used as an estimator for the population mean and is defined as: $\bar{Y}= \frac{1}{n}(Y_1 + ... +Y_n) $. If the sample is random, the single $Y_i's$ will be random and in turn the estimator $\bar{Y}$. It is random because it differs from one randomly drawn sample to another. The probability distribution of the estimator is called sampling distribution of $\bar{Y}$ and can be described by its expectation and variance. The standard deviation of $\bar{Y}$ is called standard error of the mean. As such it describes the amount of variation around the expectation of the sample mean.

A SEM closer to 0 would therefore indicate that the possible values for $\bar{Y}$ are clustered closer around the expectation of the sample mean. Since the sample mean is unbiased (its expectation equals the population mean) a SEM closer to 0 will indicate that possible values for $\bar{Y}$ are closer to the population mean. In this sense, the estimator as a statistic is more precise/accurate if the SEM is smaller. The realized value for your estimator, the estimate, is not necessarily more "accurate" compared to an estimate of an estimator with a higher SEM. But the probability that it is closer to the population mean is higher.